# How can I bind class to selected option in v-select?

Tags: css, vue.js, drop-down-menu, v-select

I want to bind a class to the selected value in my v-select. Currently I have the following:

```
<v-select :options="optionList"
          :value="activeQuote ? 'Loading ...' : null !== activeOption && activeOption.label !== 'City' ? null : activeOption"
          :placeholder="Please select a choice"
          :disabled="activeQuote">
    <template slot="option" slot-scope="option">
       <div :class="option.active != 0 ? '_inactive' : ''">{{option.label}}</div>
    </template>
</v-select>
```

However, the slot class only applies to values in the list, but not the selected value.

How can I also apply the class of '_inactive' to the selected value?

Comment: What's `v-select`? Are you using Vuetify?

Comment: it's from Vue Select package, a dropdown component

Comment: Could you provide more context ? (ie: `optionList` array) Also, I'm not sure to understand the question but if you need to apply style to the selected value, you might want to look at the [`selected-option`](https://vue-select.org/api/slots.html#selected-option) slot

Comment: I managed to use the slot selected-option and made it work, thanks!